# Will NSLog slow my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a lot of `NSLog`'s in my app - some of which often print large amounts of data - ie results of a search. Will this make an appreciable difference in the speed of my app?

I'm not familiar with macros - would someone be able to suggest one that would enable/disable all NSLogs?

Comment: Definitely NSLog can slow your app.  How serious this is obviously depends on how much you use the macro.  Most folks use some variation of a macro that can be switched on/off with either a compile flag or a runtime switch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes `NSLog` could make your app slower because of its synchronism.
To toggle all `NSLog`

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else 
#define NSLog(...)
#endif
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. Where would I put that bit of code - and where do I set the value for debug? Do I need to declare that in each file which calls NSLog?

Comment: @JoshDG you can place it in your project's `Project Name-Prefix.pch` file. The `DEBUG` constant is automatically defined by XCode when building for debugging.

Comment: How do I build for...not-debugging? I tried 'Build for running' but my the logs still printed.

Comment: @JoshDG The app is automatically compiled using the `Release` profile when you `Archive` it before send it in for the review.

Comment: When I make new project, it doesn't include the .pch file as it used to in previous releases of XCode.

Answer (score 4):

You should use something like `DLog` from [MY CURRENT PREFIX.PCH FILE](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/). It'll disable logging in the Release build. [This](http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-1-nslogdebug-ios.html) is a great explanation of why you shouldn't keep `NSLog`'s in the Release build.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is for production try to minimize them. Keep only the ones useful for errors or possible warnings. If you used them for helping you debug, then I advise you to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

YES!! too many NSLOgs will definitely slow your app.

As a best practice I usually add this in my .pch(pre compiled header file)

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DebugLog(f, ...) NSLog(f, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DebugLog(f, ...)
#endif
```

just enabled DEBUG in your preprocessor macro in build settings for debug target. Use DebugLog instead of NSLog().

Your distribution/release will not have DEBUG defined. So your app wont print anything in the log for distributed app.